# Experimental study of the Photoelectric effect

Tags: electricity, electric-circuits, photoelectric-effect

As I was reading about the experimental arrangement for photoelectric effect, I saw a diagram that puzzled my knowledge of electrodes. I found that in the experimental setup the cathode of the photoelectric plate or emitter was connected to the positive terminal of the cell. Why is it so? How can a negative electrode be connected to positive terminal of a cell?

I read Wikipedia article on cathode and it said " In a device which consumes power, the cathode is negative, and in a device which provides power, the cathode is positive". What does this mean?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/35939/11062

Comment: The Wiki article on [Cathode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cathode) and [Anode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anode) are very much satisfactorily written...

Comment: It would be a great help if you make me clear with an example about the devices that give power and consume power?

Comment: Please have a look at the Wiki articles I've linked to. Both have more or less the same explanation. The intro at the start gives some examples on the devices.